# How to ingest data from HANA to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sap-hana

This is a very basic question, but I am new to Postgres and want to ingest some data from hana views. Something like:

```
1. Run queries/stored procedure to extract/join data stored in HANA 
2. Bring into Postgres databas
```

I have pulled data from HANA through in `SQL Server` with Linked Server before but despite googling how to do it.. I can't find too much? I did find [this](https://community.sap.com/t5/technology-q-a/hana-to-from-postgresql-connection/qaq-p/11221644) link, but was quite complicated and dating back to 2015, so assuming some things have changed since.

Would